# I cannot do bootcamp but my hard disk only have machintos HD and Data

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

The bootcamp said that my disk cannot be partitioned or restored as single partition.

I am using macbook pro 15" but idk the version but the graphic card said gt320m 256 MB and 350 GB HDD i5
[image: DISK UTILITY][image: BOOTCAMP]

do i have to remove the data before do bootcamp or is there anything i can do beside remove the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing is to delete the "Data" partition and resize the Mac partition to take the whole area.

At that point, you are one click away from running BootCamp Assistant.

Options are to use Disk Utility to make an image of Data to an external drive (or perhaps to Macintosh HD if there is space). Another option is to clean as much files off Data or back it up to an external device.

It's really a balance between how valuable the files on "Data" are to you what step to take next.

Comment: the data is not really important for me because its only like a backup hd for me. so do i need to remove the data?
thanks before :)

Comment: Yes - just delete the Data partition entirely by pressing the - button in the screen shot above with Data selected. Then resize the Mac volume - pay attention to the prompts once you press "apply". Disk Utility will tell you what data gets erased and what data is preserved. You don't get an "undo" if you choose improperly and tell Disk Utility to "engage"

Comment: okay thankyou bmike its really helpful thank you so much :)